# A question about $LOAD_PATH in Ruby

Tags: ruby, path

```
$: = '/users/joecool/rubylib'
$: << '/users/joecool/rubylib'
$:.unshift('/users/joecool/rubylib')
ruby -c somescript.rb    
ruby -e "puts 'Hello, world!'
```

Can someone direct me to some reading, so that I can figure out what this code does?

Comment: Please rephrase your question!  "ruby simple question" is not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general Ruby workings, look at the Pickaxe book ([The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)).

For reference about Ruby objects and functions: http://ruby-doc.org/

For the precise questions, you may want to take a look at a list of [predefined variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_predefined_variables.htm).
`$:` is the load path, an array containing directories where libraries are searched for. It's a less readable version of `$LOAD_PATH`.

For arguments to the interpreter, you may want to look at the Unix manpage for Ruby (use '`man ruby`', or look at http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby if you don't have a Unix system in handy).

Specifically:

- `-c` checks the syntax of the script without running it.
- `-e` takes a string that is used as the script, instead of reading the script from a file.

More extensive reading: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/

Answer (score 5):

```
$: = '/users/joecool/rubylib'
```

Sets the load path to that string.

```
$: << '/users/joecool/rubylib'
```

Adds that string to the end of the load path array.

```
$:.unshift('/users/joecool/rubylib')
```

Adds that string to the beginning of the load path array.

```
ruby -c somescript.rb
```

Checks the syntax then exits.

```
ruby -e "puts 'Hello, world!'
```

Runs that Ruby snippet.  See [this reference](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html) and the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby).

Comment: So basically it does not makes much sense? :)

Comment: @will, it wouldn't make sense to do all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an introductory book about Ruby. There are many, but I would recommend that you take a look at *Beginning Ruby* by Peter Cooper or *Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas. (Those two are different enough in style and organization that one or the other is likely to fit you reasonably well.)